# What's the best colour palette for financial app?

Tags: web-app, mobile-application, color-scheme, financial

I've been working on app screens for my company.. I managed to solve some complex UX problems.. but I'm struggling with colour palettes.. as I'm a colour blind, so it's hard to figure out good colours to user to convey that they are in safe hands.. so what will be the good colour palette for financial app?

PS: it's an Android app and web app..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about branding, not user experience or usability.

Comment: I do not agree, @KristiyanLukanov. Color association and how users feel about it is an important aspect of UX. It's a big part of the message you send to your users and the world.

Comment: @NGAFD The message that you send to users and the world is called branding. UX is not message, it's what happens in reality. You achieve customer satisfaction if the message (the brand) is consistent with the reality (user experience).

Comment: @KristiyanLukanov How about the color of buttons for example. That's UX, not branding per se.

Comment: @NGAFD But the question is about color palette not about a single color of an element, like a button for example.

Comment: @KristiyanLukanov I agree, but he asks about palettes in a UX context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try to pick colours that are associated with the values of your company.**

There are a lot of great websites about colours and what they mean. I'd go for green and/or blue. Green because it is associated with money and finance. Blue because it is associated with trust, loyalty, stability, etc. These are all important to users when handling finance.

> Use green to indicate safety when advertising drugs and medical
>   products. Green is directly related to nature, so you can use it to
>   promote 'green' products. Dull, darker green is commonly associated
>   with **money, the financial world, banking, and Wall Street.**

Source: [Color Wheel Pro: Color Meaning](http://www.color-wheel-pro.com/color-meaning.html)

> Blue is the color of the sky and sea. It is often associated with
>   depth and **stability**. It symbolizes **trust**, **loyalty**, wisdom, confidence,
>   intelligence, faith, truth, and heaven.

Source: [Color Wheel Pro: Color Meaning](http://www.color-wheel-pro.com/color-meaning.html)

You can try websites like [Coolors](http://coolors.co) to experiment with different palettes.